# How do I retrieve document data, using the module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing javascript in what I believe is the module pattern (I'm still quite new to programming, so forgive me if I use incorrect terminology).

The script below is intended to measure three things when the document loads:

1. The distance the page has scrolled.
2. The y-offset of `#eventSideBar`, relative to the document top,
3. The overall height of the document.

---

```
(function (exocet, $, undefined) {

    var scrollDistance = function() {
        return $('body').scrollTop()
    }
    var sideBarOffset = function() {
        return $('#eventSideBar').offset().top;
    }
    var allHeight = function() {
        return $('body').height();
    }

    exocet.init = function() {
        console.log('Scroll distance: ' + scrollDistance() +
                    ' Sidebar offset: ' + sideBarOffset() +
                    ' Total height: ' + allHeight()
        );
    };

}(window.exocet = window.exocet || {}, jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    exocet.init();
});
```

When logging these to the console, the only value that's consistently returned correctly (tested in Chrome) is `sideBarOffset`. Whereas `scrollDistance` always returns 0 and `allHeight` varies +/- about 1000px.

If I change `exocet.init` to the following:

```
exocet.init = function() {
    console.log('Scroll distance: ' + scrollDistance() +
                ' Sidebar offset: ' + sideBarOffset() +
                ' Total height: ' + allHeight()
    );
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        console.log('Scroll is now: ' + scrollDistance());
    });
};
```

I then always get the correct scroll position value. This gets the right result, but seems a bit hackish.

Is there a "proper" way to get the data I'm after without chaining `document` methods, as seems to be happening in my approach?

Comment: What happens when you call `exocet.init()` from `$(window).load()`?

Comment: @Malk Similar results - it seems to be identical in the first case. In the second, scrollDistance is 0 about a quarter of the time.

Comment: It looks like it's working on my end [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jeqag/1/). How is the document setup and what results are you expecting?

Comment: @DavidAtchley in your example I get "Scroll distance: 200" every time, regardless of how far the page is scrolled. If, say, the page had scrolled 450px and was then refreshed - I'd expect to have "Scroll distance: 450" logged.

Comment: @Malk thanks for approving my code, but the results are too unreliable for it to be considered fine. The answer proposed by beautifulcoder seems to yield the desired effect. I do find it odd that expecting to measure a document's scroll position once it has loaded is an unreasonable expectation - could you elaborate why?

Comment: If you take all of the code in `exocet.init` and run it from `window.load` it should return the same results; meaning the module is retrieving data fine. Is that not the case?

Comment: Not really... Both methods (document.ready and window.load) are unreliable - so in that respect they match - but the data is never consistent for either.

Comment: In what use-case do you expect the scrollTop to be greater than 0 in either page.onload or document.onready? In what case does `$('body').height() !== exocet.allHeight()`?

Comment: Good question - I'm considering cases where the user goes forward or back between pages and would expect the state of the page to be recalled. Or when data is loaded via AJAX and the current scroll position will determine certain behaviours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { exocet.init(); });
```

Put that inside your ready callback. The results have to be logged when the user scrolls. Having to press refresh doesn't make much sense.

Comment: This definitely works, thank you. Pressing refresh indeed makes no sense - it was purely an example. It looks like I'll have to reconsider my code logic now though as I didn't anticipate the init function running more than once per session.

Answer (score 0):

@beautifulcoder's example will work everytime the document scrolls.  If you just want the scroll position on page load (i.e., if a scroll position was saved previously on the page), then you can put your `exocet.init()` function in a `load` event handler with a short timeout to capture that initial scroll position:

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            exocet.init();
        }, 200);
    });
```

If you want both, then use the `scroll` event handler as well.

Modified [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jeqag/1) example.

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: the `load` event doesn't wait for any initial scroll position that was saved to be scrolled to. So, the timeout gives us some leeway in waiting for that scroll to occur so we get an accurate reading.

Comment: So "that's" what the OP is asking about?  VERY, VERY unclear question if so.  I see nothing in the question about a scroll after refresh.

Comment: What I was asking is how to reliably and correctly retrieve the scroll position of a document once it has loaded. This can and may happen after a page refresh; the reason I mentioned this is because it's easy to invoke.

Comment: I apologise if this wasn't clear in my question - I thought the list of objectives and subsequent results articulated my intentions clearly enough - perhaps not. In any case, a set interval doesn't solve the issue given the variability inherent in page loading.